# How fixed typescript error in custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I use this ResizeObserver hook in my project with typescript

```
const useResizeObserver = () => {
  const [entry, setEntry] = useState<ResizeObserverEntry>();
  const [node, setNode] = useState<Element | null>(null);
  const observer = useRef<ResizeObserver | null>(null);

  const disconnect = useCallback(() => {
    const { current } = observer;
    if (current) {
      current.disconnect();
    }
  }, []);

  const observe = useCallback(() => {
    observer.current = new ResizeObserver(([entry1]) => setEntry(entry1));
    if (node) {
      observer.current.observe(node);
    }
  }, [node]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    observe();
    return () => disconnect();
  }, [disconnect, observe]);

  return [setNode, entry];
};
```

```
const [node, entry] = useResizeObserver();
<div ref={node}>content</div>
```

When i use this hook in my component, I get this error

Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<Element | null>> | ResizeObserverEntry | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLTableHeaderCellElement | null) => void) | RefObject | null | undefined'.
Type 'ResizeObserverEntry' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLTableHeaderCellElement | null) => void) | RefObject | null | undefined'.
Property 'current' is missing in type 'ResizeObserverEntry' but required in type 'RefObject'.

Help fixed

Comment: i dont know why but this hook works in js project and doesnt work with typescript

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that the issue came from typescript infer as union types as we mix an array `[setNode, entry]`. So in order to fix this issue, you simply set that as fixed return array as below:

```js
return [setNode, entry] as const;
```

Note: This const assertions is only featured from v3.4 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `setNode` as the first element in the return array and try to use it as a TableHeader `ref`.

`setNode` can't be used as a `ref`, see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) on how refs are used

Comment: LegacyAPI still allows us to set ref via callback function though